# Hilbert transform pair

Tags: signal-processing

We know the *Hilbert transform* is defined as:
$$
y(t)=\mathcal{H}(x(t))=\operatorname{P.V.}\ \left\{x(t)*\frac{1}{\pi t}\right\}
$$
In the frequency domain this is equivalent to:
$$
Y(f)=X(f)\times (-j\operatorname{sgn}(f))
$$
Using this twice, we get :
$$
Z(f)=Y(f)(-j\operatorname{sgn}(f))=X(f)(-j\operatorname{sgn}(f))^2=-X(f)\operatorname{sgn}^2(f)
$$
Many textbooks say
$$\operatorname{sgn}^2(f)=1
$$
So $$Z(f)=-X(f)
$$
and thus
$$\hat{\hat{x}}(t)=-x(t)$$
But in my mind,$$
\operatorname{sgn}(f)|_{f=0}=0$$ and if$$X(0)\neq0,$$
$$Z(0)\neq-X(0)$$
So there is a single point where $$Z(f)\neq X(f).$$
Does this matter? Or Hilbert transform is defined in ***almost everywhere*** sense?

Answer (score -1):

Any time you speak of integral operators, equality is almost always (hah) meant in the sense of almost everywhere. This makes sense since integrals don't see points; so as long as two functions only differ on some "small" set (of measure zero), we should expect to get the same output regardless.

As a note for future posts: sometimes in-line math is a good thing. Not every line of LaTeX code needs to be in an equation environment.